How to apply a radial gradient to a layer that only deals with opacity and not colors?
I have a single layer that I want to apply a radial gradient to so that the layer goes from 100% opacity in the center to 0% opacity at its edge. Is it possible to do this type of gradient without colors and just opacity?

Apply a layer mask. Add your gradient to the mask.
The mask will alter the opacity of the layer without actually altering the layer in any direct way.
